# Vuejs select form input default selection

Tags: html, vue.js

The default option ('Choose Default Meta Data') is not rendering but selected as view, anyone can help?

```html
<div class="input-field col s12">
  <select id="custom-select-f" v-model="meta_id" class="browser-default">
    <option value="" disabled :selected="meta_id ? false : true">Choose Default Meta Data</option>
    <option value="">Set As None</option>
    <option v-for="meta in metas" :value="meta.id">{{meta.data}}</option>
  </select>
  <label for="custom-select-f" class="active">Meta Data</label>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't have a disabled option selected.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of binding to the selected attribute, I gave the option a 'fake' value:
https://jsfiddle.net/DarkFruits/5mk2hrfn/

```
<select name="" id="select" v-model='name'>
  <option value="none" disabled >None</option>
  <option value="max" >Max</option>
  <option value="alex" >alex</option>
  <option v-for='n in names' :value="n">{{n}}</option>
</select>

new Vue({
    el: '#select',
    data() {
    return {
      names: ['Sandy', 'Pete'],
        name: 'none',
    }
  }
})
```